# Link button to HTML specific section

Tags: html, button

I'm trying to link my button to a specific section of my website, this is the code:

````
```      
<div>
        <button class="btn btn-opacity-light mr-1" a class="nav-link" <a href="#features-section"></a>Empezar Ahora</button>
      </div>```
````

and this is the section im trying to link it:

````
```  
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <section class="features-overview" id="features-section" >
        <div class="content-header">
          <h2>Experiencia EPCE</h2>
          <h6 class="section-subtitle text-muted">En EPCE nos centramos en brindar el conocimiento y la experiencia que el mercado laboral y profesional requiere, a través de diversos instructores especializados en distintos campos. Brindamos una metodología única y acorde a los desafíos actuales, mediante el desarrollo de casos reales y asimilación de conocimiento.</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
          <div class="grid-margin d-flex justify-content-start">
            <div class="features-width">
              <img src="images/Group12.svg" alt="" class="img-icons">
              <h5 class="py-3">Aprende</h5>
              <p class="text-muted">Nuevos conocimientos a través de las sesiones educativas y aplicación práctica.</p> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-margin d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="features-width">
              <img src="images/Group7.svg" alt="" class="img-icons">
              <h5 class="py-3">Vive</h5>
              <p class="text-muted">La amplia gama de experiencias brindada por nuestros instructores.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-margin d-flex justify-content-end">
            <div class="features-width">
              <img src="images/Group5.svg" alt="" class="img-icons">
              <h5 class="py-3">Innova</h5>
              <p class="text-muted">Con soluciones efectivas a través de las herramientas y conocimientos brindados en EPCE.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section> ```
````

Hope someone can help me out thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```html
<a href="#features-section" class="btn btn-opacity-light mr-1 nav-link">
Empezar Ahora
</a>
```

EDIT:

If your button become huge, add a class to it, like "home-button" and add:

```css
        .home-button {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
        }
```

to your CSS stylesheet

Comment: Because the button becomes huge, look: https://imgur.com/a/hD6iS8Z

Comment: In this case, add a class to your "a" and set "display: block" to it, then set width if needed

Comment: May you please send me the code of it? I'm not getting it... =(

Comment: Nope, didn't work: https://imgur.com/mCWP3op

Comment: Edited again after tests, does it works for you?

Comment: Now I get the color back, but its not centered...

Answer (score 0):

this works fine

```html
a href="#features-section" type="button" class="btn btn-opacity-light mr-1 nav-link">
        Empezar Ahora
        </a>
```